# Limits in metric spaces

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(X, \rho)$ be a metric space. Let $f,g: (S, \rho) \to\mathbb{R}$ be functions.  Show that if $\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x) = A > 0$, then for every $r \in (0, A)$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that for every $x \in B_{\delta}(x_0) \setminus \{x_0\}$, we have $f(x) > r> 0$.

---

Since the codomain is $\mathbb{R}$, we use the normal definition of a limit. Other than this though, i'm not sure how to start off. So for all $x$ in the ball with the missing center, we have $f(x) > r > 0$. Okay. But i'm not sure how to use the information we have.

Comment: Please, state more carefully your problem: what's the role of $g$? What's $S$? Why $\delta$ becomes $d$?

Comment: I think you will be close to finishing this exercise if you state more fully "the normal definition of a limit" (or any other definition that will serve in this context).

Comment: Yes, @hardmath it would have been easy like that. I was simply stuck for whatever reason. Egreg, $g$ is used for a second part of the problem

Answer (score 1):

I assume that $S$ is some subset of $X$ such that $x_0$ is an accumulation point of $S$.

The fact that $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=A$ tells you that, for every $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that, $x\in S\cap(B_\delta(x_0)\setminus\{x_0\})$, $|f(x)-A|<\varepsilon$.

Now, take $0<r<A$ and consider $\varepsilon=A-r$. Then, for the suitable $\delta$ given by the definition above, when $x\in S\cap(B_\delta(x_0)\setminus\{x_0\})$ you have
$$
A-(A-r)<f(x)<A+(A-r)
$$
which in particular means $f(x)>r$.